# Get the size of the queue in linux

Tags: linux

How can i get the exact size of the following table or queue. It can be seem, it has five rows. I just want to print the number 5 as an output. Please help

```
| E1     | E2                      | E3       | E4      | E5    | E6          |
+--------+-------------------------+----------+---------+-------+-------------+
| 244000 | 2017-10-19T11:25:16.384 | service2 | WAITING |       |           7 |
| 245000 | 2017-10-17T10:25:16.384 | service3 | WAITING |       |           7 |
| 241000 | 2017-10-20T13:25:16.384 | service  | WAITING |       |           7 |
| 242000 | 2017-10-20T13:25:16.384 | service  | WAITING |       |           7 |
| 243000 | 2017-10-21T13:25:16.384 | service1 | WAITING |       |           7 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe your output to this

```
grep -c WAITING
```

-c is to return count of matching patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Count occurrences of "WATING" in given sequence via simple program?

Python code:

```
filename = 'table.txt'             // your file path
f = open(filename, 'r')            // open file
print(f.read().count('WAITING'))   // count how many time 'WAITING' apears and print it
```

If other states than 'WATING' can apear count also their occurrences and print sum.

Answer (score 0):

In bash you can run command  `grep -w "WAITING"| wc -l`. This will search for pattern WAITING and count the number of lines.